# shared pointer forward declaration

Tags: c++, typedef, forward-declaration, shared-ptr

I have an interface `Interface`.
I also have a .h file `InterfaceFwd.h` which looks something like

```
#ifndef Blah
#define Blah
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
class Interface;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Interface> InterfacePtr;
#endif
```

I also have Interface.h

```
#ifndef SomeOtherBlah
#define SomeOtherBlah
class Interface
{
   virtual ~Interface()
   { 
   }
   ... 
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Interface> InterfacePtr;
#endif
```

Do I need to worry that if both files are included there will be duplicate declaration of InterfacePtr? On my compiler this compiles fine, but does the standard One-Definition Rule allow multiple identical typedef-declarations? Also, do you think I should include `InterfaceFwd.h` into `Interface.h` instead of redeclaring `InterfacePtr` or it's fine as it is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one definition rule doesn't apply to `typedef`s. A `typedef` (on its own) doesn't define a new variable, function, class type, enumeration type or template. You are explicitly allowed to redefine a previous *typedef-name* to refer to the type that it already refers to.

7.1.3 [dcl.typedef]:

> In a given non-class scope, a `typedef` specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.